# Hibernate @Filter with @Cache not working

Tags: hibernate, caching, spring-boot, filter, one-to-many

I have the entity **FormTable** that has one to many relationship with another entity **FormInLangagueTable**, I want to filter out the in language entities (based on dynamic parameter), and return the final object with the list of in language objects that match the filter paramater.

I managed to achieve that with @Filter and @FilterDef, which is working as expected, **except the cache doesn't occur** and the database get's a hit **every query**.

I found the [following JIRA issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11066), seems I'm not the first with this problem...

I'm completly lost, how can I filter the list of FormInLangagueTable based on dynamic parameter, while maintaining the 2 level cache?

Thanks!

**FormTable:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FORM")
@FilterDef(name = "userLanguageFilter", parameters = {
        // Set by the dao, to filter out irrelevant captions
        @ParamDef(name = "languageIdParam", type = "short")
})
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
public class FormTable {
    private Integer formId;

    ...

    /**
     * All the available language translations for the given form, won't be presented in the json response.
     */
    private List<FormInLanguageFactoryTable> formInLanguages;
    /**
     * Manually fetched from {@link #formInLanguages}, the language used
     * <b>specific to the user</b>, will be returned by the json.
     */
    private String specificLanguageCaption;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "_FormId")
    public Integer getFormId() {
        return formId;
    }

    public void setFormId(Integer formId) {
        this.formId = formId;
    }

    /**
     * Get all the form title in the corresponding languages, then filter it only to the current user language.
     * It <b>will not be presented in the final json,
     * but used in {@link #getSpecificLanguageCaption} to get the string, or null if none found.</b>
     */
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "_FormId", referencedColumnName = "_FormId")
    @Filter(name = "userLanguageFilter", condition = "_LanguageId = :languageIdParam")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    @JsonIgnore
    public List<FormInLanguageTable> getFormInLanguages() {
        return formInLanguages;
    }

    public void setFormInLanguages(List<FormInLanguageTable> languageCaption) {
        this.formInLanguages = languageCaption;
    }

    /**
     * Will convert {@link #getFormInLanguages} into a string (the form caption, or null if none found)
     * @return
     */
    @Transient
    @JsonProperty("languageCaption")
    public String getSpecificLanguageCaption() {
        return this.getFormInLanguages().isEmpty() ? null : this.getFormInLanguages().get(0).getCaption();
    }
}
```

**FormInLanguage:**

```
/**
 * The available languages for the given form
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "FormInLanguage")
@Cache(usage= CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
public class FormInLanguageTable {
    private PK id;
    private String caption;

    @EmbeddedId
    @JsonIgnore
    public PK getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(PK id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "Caption")
    public String getCaption() {
        return caption;
    }

    public void setCaption(String caption) {
        this.caption = caption;
    }

    @Embeddable
    public static class PK implements Serializable {
        private Integer formId;
        private Short languageId;

        @Column(name = "_FormId")
        @JsonIgnore
        public Integer getFormId() {
            return formId;
        }

        public void setFormId(Integer formId) {
            this.formId = formId;
        }

        @Column(name = "_LanguageId")
        public Short getLanguageId() {
            return languageId;
        }

        public void setLanguageId(Short formFieldId) {
            this.languageId = formFieldId;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. 
Until now, I found this:

> It’s not possible to combine the @Filter and @Cache collection
>   annotations. This limitation is due to ensuring consistency and
>   because the filtering information is not stored in the second-level
>   cache.
>
> If caching was allowed for a currently filtered collection, then the
>   second-level cache would store only a subset of the whole collection.
>   Afterward, every other Session will get the filtered collection from
>   the cache, even if the Session-level filters have not been explicitly
>   activated.
>
> For this reason, the second-level collection cache is limited to
>   storing whole collections, and not subsets.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-column-filter

I'm still looking for a solution...

Comment: Yeah I as well found this after posting the question, and it does make sense, using the filter creates a filtered version of the data, which mean it must either stores the whole dataset and apply the filter each time, or cache the dataset with each filter used. both demand memory. I found using *Spring boot cache annotations to cache service methods* much more effective (you also have much more control over the cache, aka when to evict, what identifiers are registered for it etc...)